# Export nested array as xlsx format

Tags: javascript, excel, reactjs, antd

I am using Antd table to show list of data.I need to export the table data as excel file. I am currently using [react-export-excel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-export-excel) package. but i am not sure how to handle the nested array of objects.I am using the following dummy data.

```
const data = [
  {
     "id": 83,
     "name": "Tim",      
     "reports": [
        {
           "id": 4,
           "self": 0,
           "year": 2019,
           "month": 12,
           "appraiser": 0
        },
        {
           "id": 5,
           "self": 0,
           "year": 2020,
           "month": 1,
           "appraiser": 0
        },
        {
           "id": 6,
           "self": 0,
           "year": 2020,
           "month": 2,
           "appraiser": 0
        }, {
           "id": 7,
           "self": 0,
           "year": 2020,
           "month": 8,
           "appraiser": 0
        },
     ],
     "average": 0
  },
  {
     "id": 91,
     "name": "Jhon",       
     "reports": [
        {
           "id": 8,
           "self": 0,
           "year": 2019,
           "month": 12,
           "appraiser": 0
        },
        {
           "id": 9,
           "self": 0,
           "year": 2020,
           "month": 1,
           "appraiser": 0
        },
        {
           "id": 10,
           "self": 0,
           "year": 2020,
           "month": 2,
           "appraiser": 0
        }, {
           "id": 11,
           "self": 0,
           "year": 2020,
           "month": 8,
           "appraiser": 0
        },
     ],
     "average": 0
  }]
```

**Export.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactExport from "react-export-excel";

const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;
const ExcelColumn = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelColumn;

const exportReport = ({ report }) => {

return (
    <ExcelFile element={downloadButton}>
        <ExcelSheet data={report} name="Report">
            <ExcelColumn label="Id" value="id"></ExcelColumn>
            <ExcelColumn label="Name" value="name"></ExcelColumn>
            <ExcelColumn label="Average" value="average"></ExcelColumn>
        </ExcelSheet>
    </ExcelFile>
)
}

export default exportReport
```

I am not sure do i structure the data so that i get the output like this

```
| id |       January-2020 |      February-2020 |average| 
|--------|----------------|-----------------|
|         self | appraiser  self | appraiser
         |----------------|---------------- |          |
| 83     |   0  |    0    |  0     |    0   |      0   |
| 91     |   0  |    0    |  0     |    0   |      0   |
```

Comment: could you make a code sandbox ?

Comment: @blueseal sure!. please check https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-snow-k3mol?from-embed

Comment: "I am currently using react-export-excel package." - your code sandbox doesn't have the "react-export-excel" package.

Comment: @blueseal seems react-export-excel uses xlsx library under the hood. it doesn't handle complex JSON structure. i have used xlsx to structure the data which works for me. I will update the answer soon. Thanks anyway!